# aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 / "R" Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using a localHTML webview app. It's a basic webView android application ,using a exported html of a website.

- I used this source code before and it work fine, but then i changed a few things in the web, and exported the same way, the same domain, same folder names etc. But now, when i replace the assests folder i get an error
- [Here's the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsHCM.png)
- Also when i change the assets folder even if everything is the same expect a few more index html and images. The "R" goes "cannot resolve symbol R"

-- code --

```
  package com.zeeroapps.loadlocalhtml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mwebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mwebview= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mwebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mwebview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    try {
        mwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/beyazsapka.net/55x2/index.html");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mwebview.canGoBack())
        mwebview.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

**Things i tried so far**

1. Chaning buildToolsVersion from 23.0.3, to 22.x.x, 21.x,x , 20.x.x and so on..
2. Cleaning and Rebuilding App
3. Updating the SDK

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Please include the text of the error (put a > before it to format) and the text of your code (use four spaces to format) rather than links to figures.

Comment: In your assets folder is there any file which have '-' character in its name? If you do have '-' then rename that file to something without that character.